# Removing images with all 0s from collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, imagecollection

I have an image collection that contains a series of images (1 per year) from a previous analytical step. As part of that analysis, a dummy image (a 5-band image containing all 0s) was created for empty years that did not have any associated data. This was intentional for a different processing pipeline. I need to now remove those dummy images from the collection. The final result should be an image collection that excludes any years (images) with all 0 values.My current approach was to check if the image contains non-zero values, then use that condition to filter based on content. However, this returns the full image collection rather than removing the empty images. Suggestions for better approaches are more than welcome. Thanks!

```
// Dummy collection ex
var fakeCollection = ee.ImageCollection([
  ee.Image.constant(0).rename('band').set('system:index', 'zero_image'),  // Zero image - I do not want to filter by properties. 
  ee.Image.random(1).multiply(100).int16().rename('band').set('system:index', 'random_image_1'),  
  ee.Image.random(2).multiply(200).int16().rename('band').set('system:index', 'random_image_2')   
]);

var filtered = fakeCollection
  .map(function (image) {
    var include = image.not().eq(0) // trying to create a condition that will check for non-zero values...
    return ee.Image(ee.Algorithms.If(include, image, null))
  }, true) // Result should be an image collection with only 2 images, but is returning all 3.
```

Answer (score 1):

Filtering only works on whole images (think of an image collection as a table with each image being one row; filtering only works over table columns, not pixel values).

Your best bet would have been to give the original blank images an additional metadata property so you could filter them out directly. (Or refactor your code to not need blank images at all).

But assuming that wasn't practical for some reason, you'll have to check that every pixel is zero, in every image, using a mapped reduceRegion.  Maybe using an `anyNonZero` reducer.